# Category being displayed without base parmalink

Tags: categories, permalinks, archives

My permalinks are set as
/%category%/%postname%/

But I am getting duplicate pages
domain.com/category/jazz is also the same as domain.com/jazz

I do not want domain.com/jazz to display as an archive page.

I have disabled yoast and still getting the problem.
Any ideas on how to fix this?